# How to force to show PDF in google chrome using Adobe PDF Plug-In only

Tags: pdf, google-chrome, plugins, adobe

I am facing a problem while showing a pdf in Google Chrome. The issue is that Chrome shows some pages of the pdf as black.

This happens when Chrome PDF Viewer is enabled. If I disable this plug-in and use Adobe PDF Plug-In it works fine.

Is there any way to show a PDF in Google Chrome using the Adobe PDF Plug-In only.

AS I am showing PDF using an HTML object tag, is there any parameter which forces Chrome to show the PDF using Adobe PDF Plug-In?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way for a website to force the browser to use one renderer or another: those decisions are all made client-side. As you noted, disabling the Chrome PDF plugin bubbles the Adobe plugin to the top, but that's a decision the user would have to make.

That said, if you have a PDF with rendering issues that you can share, please file a bug at http://new.crbug.com/. I'll be happy to put it in front of the correct team for triage.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can be 100% that all users can open your PDF correctly currently, is to force that the PDF is downloaded.

Use some headers within your apache or backend.

Example for Apache
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11991050/3086639