# Mailto links in pdf not working in Chrome's pdf viewer

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf

[Here's the form in question](http://www.townofleland.com/Images/TownOfLeland/site/police/parking_permit_application_2013_3__1_.pdf)

The "Email" button in the top right is just a mailto link, and it doesn't work in chrome's pdf reader. Any idea what's happening? It works just fine in acrobat.

Answer (score 2):

It's unfortunately a limitation of the built-in PDF viewers in Chrome and Firefox. If you want the file to open in Acrobat, you have to force the browser to download the file rather than open it. You can do this in modern browsers using the HTML5 download attribute:

```
<a href="form.pdf" download="form.pdf">Download Form</a>
```

This link has more details: http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute

For a more widely compatible solution, you would have to use the `Content-disposition` header. It's possible to do this with PHP, there is an example here: [How to force PDF to download beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990902/how-to-force-pdf-to-download-beginner)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but it may help someone to keep in mind that mailto doesn't work in Chrome's PDF viewer (and in Adobe Acrobat Reader as well) if it has line break in it. Hyperlink has to be in one line!

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a limitation of Chrome's PDF reader, possibly because of security reasons. The mailto link launches the installed email application and Chrome probably wants to avoid some problems.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my mailto link has a special character (**à**) that causes it to not work in the browser.
It got resolved by changing the special character (**à**) to a normal letter (**a**).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPXmD.png)