# Auto upload file to Google Drive every week

Tags: php, wordpress, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm getting a zip file (it includes 100-200 csv files) URL every week from an API call using cron job. I want to use the URL to download the zip file locally and then extract that file and then upload all the csv files to Google Drive to a particular folder.

Any idea on how to go about this?

Thanks.

PS: ZIP File will be saved in a themes folder in WordPress. (if that helps)

Answer (score 0):

To auto upload files to Google Drive, you need to use REST API SErvice of google developer console, Refer https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/simple-upload.

You can use PHP Force download to auto download files ([How to force PDF to download beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990902/how-to-force-pdf-to-download-beginner)).