# How to edit chrome:plugin setting through Javascript / PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome, plugins, browser

The problem is I would like to edit the

```
chrome://plugins/
```

Instead of input the url to address bar and turn on the plugin manually, I would like to know are there any way to change the settings through the javascript/ php ? e.g. I would like to turn off the web visitor default pdf viewer and turn on the adobe viewer. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force to show PDF in google chrome using Adobe PDF Plug-In only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615751/how-to-force-to-show-pdf-in-google-chrome-using-adobe-pdf-plug-in-only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply don't have permission to do this from a webpage - Chrome (and other browsers) will not allow you to specify the plugins an end user is allowed to use. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615751/how-to-force-to-show-pdf-in-google-chrome-using-adobe-pdf-plug-in-only) for a previous discussion on this.