# How to display 3D PDF in Chrome & Firefox Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, pdf

I've to display 3D PDF in browser and few browsers doesn't support 3D PDF like Chrome, Firefox, Mobile browser.

How can we detect / update the default PDF viewer plugin in Chrome & Firefox through code?

Can detect Adobe Reader plugins for all the browser as well using this [code](http://thecodeabode.blogspot.in/2011/01/detect-adobe-reader-plugin.html).

My query is I want to disable the default PDF viewer plugin and enable Adobe Reader plugin through code [javascript]. Is there any possible solution for this?

Comment: The linked duplicate contains a reply from someone from the Chromium team, the answer for Firefox is similar. Besides, not everyone has Adobe installed. Feature request for 3D PDFs in PDF.js (Firefox's PDF reader) is here: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/3254

Comment: You can view 3D PDF in Chrome as well as in Firefox by making few updates of the addons. Will update description in my question soon but wanted to know how to make those addons changes programatically.

Comment: The solutions you've highlighted are more for users. You cannot change these settings through your web app. Don't force Adobe Reader upon your users. At most show a warning that the PDF might not display properly because Adobe reader is not detected. There might be a chance that the user has a PDF reader that is capable of viewing U3D objects, and locking these out would not be so nice.

Comment: Agreed. But initially when I posted this question, you mentioned that it is not at possible to view 3D PDF in Chrome and Firefox and even everywhere on web and stack overflow it has been mentioned that 3D PDF can't be viewed in Chrome & Firefox. But after long research, I found that it is possible to view 3D PDF in Chrome & Firefox and still looking for the solutions for same. But yes I found temporary solution that if PDF is not loaded [using adobe reader] in firefox or chrome, system will display a message which will lead to a page on which we've displayed help / tutorial.

Comment: So it's not duplicate question. And better if you remove duplicate flag on this question. Because this question or solution is not there on stack overflow anywhere and not at least in this thread you mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615751/how-to-force-to-show-pdf-in-google-chrome-using-adobe-pdf-plug-in-only

Comment: I did not allege that is it impossible to display 3D PDFs, I just pointed out that it is impossible to force the browser to use Adobe Reader in all browsers through JavaScript. If you edit your question to more accurately represent the intended question (displaying 3D PDFs in a browser?), then I will re-open the question.

Comment: Updated the question title, now could you please reopen the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got work around to display 3D PDF in Chrome but disabling the default PDF Viewer plugins and enabling the Adobe Reader plugins from chrome://plugins/ in chrome browser.

Chrome Plugins Settings:

[image: Chrome Plugins Settings]

Firefox Plugins Settings:
[image: Firefox Plugins Settings]

But still looking for this settings to be updated from code.

Comment: Any luck on this yet? I'm faced with similar dilemma. It's doubtful you will find a way to change a user's browser settings programmatically, as that would be a big security violation.

Answer (score 0):

Since Google has disabled the NPAPI support, therefore, Adobe reader cannot be configured to view PDF file within Chrome and many other modern browsers. See link below:

https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/change-in-support-for-acrobat-and-reader-plug-ins-in-modern-web-.html