# Displaying 3D PDF in the Latest Chrome after the removal of NPAPI support

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf, 3d, adobe-reader

I am looking to display a 3D PDF file in the Chrome browser and tried almost all the options, including the solution discussed in the following question.

[How to display 3D PDF in Chrome & Firefox Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059121/how-to-display-3d-pdf-in-chrome-firefox-browser)

Since Google has disabled the NPAPI support as mentioned in the link below, therefore, the solution mentioned in the above link seems not working any more.

https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/change-in-support-for-acrobat-and-reader-plug-ins-in-modern-web-.html

According to my search, the Adobe Acrobat reader can not be used to view the PDF file within the chrome browser.

I am also open to any alternative approach that displays 3d model, created in AutoCAD, using HTML on Chrome browser

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need full 3D viewing, such as rotation of the 3D model? Or fixed 2D view(s) of the model? Can you post/link an example PDF?

Comment: Yes, full 3D Viewing. Here is the [example](https://tetra4d.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/PartList-Helico.pdf), taken from the internet. Thanks

Comment: There are no browser-based PDF viewers that will display 3D PDF.